# Rails adding a new link in the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

i am trying to adding a new link to make a form for a join table, the link gives and error saying that no routes for that, i am using rails api

```
<%= link_to("Add New Alarm/List", {:action => 'new_alarm', :controller =>'alarms'}, :class => 'action new') %>
```

any help please
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you paste the error also?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be able to use the alarms routes, providing you have `resources :alarms` in your routes file. To check the routes you can use you can run `rake routes`.

```
<%= link_to "Add New Alarm/List", new_alarm_path, :class => 'action new' %>
```

edit:

`resources :alarms` sets up the new_alarm_path by using the `new` method in your alarms_controller and the `new.html.erb` file in your alarms/ folder. If you have the new method defined in your controller and the new html file is just called new.html.erb, your above code should work if you used `{:action => 'new'`

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, but where to define the new_alarm_path to point to the new action in the controller, 
and what about if i want to make a new definition in the controller, for a new "new" method for example "new2"

Comment: when you set up resources :alarms, it should automatically set up the route for new_alarm_path, if you want to use a link for another method (needs to be defined in your alarms controller as `new_alarm`) you could use `<%= link_to("Add new", {:action => 'new_alarm', :controller => 'alarms' }) %>` although you should probably try make use of the default routes (i.e. new_alarm_path for the new method), why are you wanting a second new method?

Comment: for example i want to make a new page that adding an alarm to a list, for example, but when the url is http://localhost:3000/alarms/new2, the system deals with the url as if it is show and wants to find alarm with id 'new2' and ofcourse it get an error that it could not find this id

Comment: You could try:
`get 'alarms/new2', to: 'articles#new2', as: 'new2'` in your routes file